# Links to location on same page not matching up

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, scrollview, css-transitions

I need your help.

I made a nav bar that links to anchor locations on the same page, allowing the view port to scroll down when clicked(nothing complicated).

The problem: There is a big cover page up at the top that uses web transitions and shrinks a height of 0. The nav links think there is a big page in the way and scroll down too far.

Does anyone have a solution?? Maybe Jquery that detects scrollTop() and uses if statements to adjust/offset() the location??

HERE IS THE LINK: [www.imbenton.com][1]

Code:

```
    var $window = $(window);    
    $window.bind('scroll', function(){  
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();    

        if (pos > 2){
            $('#cover').addClass("alt");
            $('#cover img').addClass("alt");
            $('.logo').addClass("alt");
            $('nav').addClass("still");
            $('.navhead').addClass("still");
        }   
        if (pos < 1){
            $('nav').removeClass("alt");    
            $('#cover').removeClass("alt");
            $('#cover img').removeClass("alt");         
            $('.logo').removeClass("alt");
            $('nav').removeClass("still");
            $('.navhead').removeClass("still");
        }       
});
```

----------- CSS ----------

```
#cover img{ 
    max-width: 90%; 
    padding: 300px 0 600px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
          transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}


#cover img.alt{
background: url("dvsup.png") repeat fixed;  
    max-width: 0%;  
    padding: 100px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
} 

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 173px;
    padding: 0px 0 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
    z-index: 999;

}
nav.still{
    position: fixed;
    top: -980px;
    padding-top: 900px;
    background: url("dvsup.png") repeat fixed;  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is kind of cool but also kind of a bad experience too. Can you post some code as to how it works?

You can always have the cover page as an overlay on top that way the height should be calculated correctly or if you know the difference in height that's getting miscalculated you can always adjust the scroll y position

Update:

I have an untested idea, use jquery to put padding or margin to the top of your content (not cover page). This space should be equals to the height of the cover page. This might correct the calculation, you will have to test it out. Can you also post some html? Unless the links are just internal links then don't worry about the html

Comment: Thanks. Bad experience huh... how can i make it better? quickleft.com has a similar banner. If I do an overlay, the experience is worse because it hides important content.

Comment: well if your page is meant to be flashy then leave as is and just try to fix the height thing. I will have to spend some time to look at the code